# Is Oauth redirect_uri in authorization grant type a html page or api call?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I have a confusion on, whether the redirect_uri in OAUTH authorization grant type, a html page or an API call?

Answer (score 0):

The [redirect_uri](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.1.2) in OAuth2 is the endpoint where the client receives the authorization code (authorization code) or access token (implicit grant).

The authorization server typically redirects the user's browser back to the client via an `HTTP 302` redirect status code.

However, Openid Connect defines a [`response_mode=form_post`](https://openid.net/specs/oauth-v2-form-post-response-mode-1_0.html), which makes the authorization server return a HTML page with a form containing the parameters as (hidden) fields that is auto-submitted to the client application.

Comment: So it can be either api call or html page. Is it?

Comment: Not an API call as it's not returning any data. It receives data via a GET or POST request. It processes the data (get token, create session cookie etc) and redirect to another endpoint in the client.